Nextjs app. Everything runs well in Dev environment. npm run build gives an error
I am getting the following error when trying to build Nextjs app.
Generating static pages (0/20)  [=   ]TypeError: u is not a function at m (C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\.next\server\app\(brewery)\test\Customers\page.js:1:9038) at em (C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:131226) at C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:142926 at Array.toJSON (C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:146504) at stringify (<anonymous>) at eR (C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:134889) at eP (C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:135332) at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14) at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:146956) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17) TypeError: u is not a function at m (C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\.next\server\app\(brewery)\test\Customers\page.js:1:9038) at em (C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:131226) at C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:142926 at Array.toJSON (C:\Users\coool\Documents\AnalyticsBrewery\analytics-brewery-a1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:146504)
Here is the code Customer\page.jsx.
// pages/customers.js

import { QueryDataFromSupabase } from "@/lib/db";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

function CustomerPage() {
  let qStr = 'SELECT * FROM "Customer" LIMIT 5;';
  const x = useQuery({ queryKey: ["customers"], queryFn: QueryDataFromSupabase(qStr, "sqlRows") });

  console.log("Fetching customers from Supabase:", customers);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Customer Info</h1>
      {customers.map((customer, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {/* Display customer info here */}
          <p>{customer.name}</p>
          {/* Add more customer details as needed */}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomerPage;

Please help with the error message.
I was expecting npm run build to complete without any error.

You're passing the QueryDataFromSupabase function directly to the queryFn option of useQuery, it's looking for a function to return a promise.
You need to modify the useQuery hook to handle the query function correctly.
See if this works for you
import { QueryDataFromSupabase } from "@/lib/db";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

function CustomerPage() {
  let qStr = 'SELECT * FROM "Customer" LIMIT 5;';
  const { data: customers, isLoading, error } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["customers"],
    queryFn: () => QueryDataFromSupabase(qStr, "sqlRows"),
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  }

  console.log("Fetched customers from Supabase:", customers);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Customer Info</h1>
      {customers.map((customer, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {/* Display customer info here */}
          <p>{customer.name}</p>
          {/* Add more customer details as needed */}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomerPage;


Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I realized my mistake.

No problem, if you could mark this one as solved I'd highly appreciate it =)
